# Flutter : Different style Previous & Next Item on PageViewBuilder

Tags: flutter

[image]

I have design on figma and want implement it to flutter, where previous & next item slightly away from the main item.

## Dummy class

```
const urlImageTesting = 'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/girl.png';
class RecentPlay {
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String imageUrl;

  RecentPlay({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.imageUrl,
  });
}

final List<RecentPlay> listRecentPlay = [
  RecentPlay(
    id: 1,
    title: 'Shigatsu wa kimi Uso # OP 2-Nanairo Symphony',
    imageUrl: urlImageTesting,
  ),
  RecentPlay(
    id: 2,
    title: 'Shigatsu wa kimi Uso # OP 2-Nanairo Symphony',
    imageUrl: urlImageTesting,
  ),
  RecentPlay(
    id: 3,
    title: 'Shigatsu wa kimi Uso # OP 2-Nanairo Symphony',
    imageUrl: urlImageTesting,
  ),
  RecentPlay(
    id: 4,
    title: 'Shigatsu wa kimi Uso # OP 2-Nanairo Symphony',
    imageUrl: urlImageTesting,
  ),
  RecentPlay(
    id: 5,
    title: 'Shigatsu wa kimi Uso # OP 2-Nanairo Symphony',
    imageUrl: urlImageTesting,
  ),
];
```

## HomeScreen

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final _pageController = PageController(viewportFraction: .7);
  int _currentIndexPageView = 0;

  void setCurrentIndex(int index) {
    setState(() => _currentIndexPageView = index);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        left: 16.0,
        right: 16.0,
      ),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          SizedBox.expand(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Text(
                    'Baru saja diputar',
                    style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 500,
                    child: PageView.builder(
                      controller: _pageController,
                      itemCount: listRecentPlay.length,
                      onPageChanged: setCurrentIndex,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final result = listRecentPlay[index];
                        var offset = Offset(0, 0);
                        if (index != _currentIndexPageView) {
                          if (index + 1 < listRecentPlay.length) {
                            print('next Index');
                            offset = Offset(-10, 0);
                          }

                          if (index - 1 > -1) {
                            print('previoues Index');
                            offset = Offset(10, 0);
                          }
                        }
                        return Transform.translate(
                          offset: offset,
                          child: Container(
                            child: ShowImageNetwork(
                              imageUrl: result.imageUrl,
                              imageBorderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              imageSize: 1,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is, previous & next index style i defined is inconsistent, the result was successful only on the first try, when the next item swipe did not match expectations

[image]

Did I make mistake ?

Comment: check https://gist.github.com/pskink/c04de9b3d643b14051a6bca5189985c1, it is up to you what you return from `AnimatedBuilder`

Comment: @pskink already try copy & paste your gist , but i get undefined **ui** & **math**, already import `dart:math` but not fixed the problem

Comment: `import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'dart:math' as math;`